# QT 6.x multimedia - connect microphone audio to send to speaker and udp network simultaneously

Tags: c++, qt, qt6, qtmultimedia

I asked this question directly on the [QT desktop support forum](https://forum.qt.io/topic/140601/connecting-microphone-audio-and-sending-to-speaker-and-udp-network-simultaneously) but unfortunately I am not having any success there.  Hopefully with the larger stackoverflow audience I will have better luck here.

I need to capture audio from the microphone QAudioSource and forward it to both the speakers QAudioSink and simultaneously over the network wrapped in RTP headers.  I am not sure how to do this.

Right now I reliably play synthesized audio tones to the speaker from a custom QIODevice (***std::unique_ptr mpIODeviceSink*** opened in ***readOnly*** mode) containing preformatted audio tone data (sine waves).  I based this work off of the ***[audio output sample](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/qtmultimedia-multimedia-audiooutput-example.html)*** that ships with QT 6.x.  Once the QAudioSink is opened (***QWindowsAudioSink*** in my case) it regularly requests data reads of variable sized buffers from the mpIODeviceSink (contaning the tone data).  The Sink is opened by default in "pull" mode using a QTimer in the QAudioSink under the covers.   I presume this timer sees when the speaker runs out of data and keeps requesting more the mpIODeviceSink to keep the audio from underruns.

Also within this same worker thread, I have a ***QAudioSource*** (microphone default input device) feeding another QIODevice (***std::unique_ptr mpIODeviceSource which is *** opened in writeOnly mode).  Whenever the microphone captures audio, it writes it ***mpIODeviceSource*** (using the following connect call (this is based off of the audio input example with Qt 6.x)  - I have a custom ***audioCaptured*** signal that I emit from ***mpIODeviceSource*** whenever data is captured from the microphone allowing me to send it to the network - right now I just log it).

I was thinking that I could use an intermediate QIODevice (like a QBuffer or a subclass of it) opened in read/write mode that could share its buffers between the microphone (input) and the speaker & ideally the UDPSocket as outputs.  (1 input to 2 outputs). I have no idea if this is the correct approach, of if I need to subclass a QAudioSink & associate that with the UDPSocket IODevice in order to transmit fixed size UDP frames to a remote RTP listener device.

The tricky thing is that these UDP frames are fixed size datagrams and should transmitted at regular intervals to maintain good audio.

```
    connect(mpIODeviceSource.get(), &IODeviceSource::audioCaptured,
        this, &RtpWorker::handleAudioCaptured, Qt::UniqueConnection);
```

Here is the RtpWorker class in question

```
#pragma once

// SYSTEM INCLUDES
#include <QTimer>
#include <QThread>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QAudioSink>
#include <QAudioSource>
#include <spdlog/common.h>

// APPLICATION INCLUDES
#include "rtp/rtp.h"
#include "IODeviceSink.h"
#include "IODeviceSource.h"

// DEFINES
// EXTERNAL FUNCTIONS
// EXTERNAL VARIABLES
// CONSTANTS
// STRUCTS
// TYPEDEFS
// FORWARD DECLARATIONS
class QTimer;
class QTimerEvent;
class QUdpSocket;
class QAudioSource;
class QAudioBuffer;
class QAudioSink;

const auto gHeaderLenLambda = [](const QByteArray& rRawHeader)->qsizetype {
    const auto header = reinterpret_cast<const rtp_hdr_t*>(rRawHeader.constData());
    qsizetype headerLen = sizeof(rtp_hdr_t) + header->cc * sizeof(uint32_t);
    // header extension
    if (header->x != 0u) {
        const auto ext = reinterpret_cast<const rtp_hdr_ext_t*>(
            rRawHeader.constData() + headerLen);
        const auto ext_len = ntohs(ext->len);
        headerLen += static_cast<qsizetype>(
            sizeof(uint32_t) + (ext_len * sizeof(uint32_t)));
    }
    // must have sufficient bytes in raw header
    if (headerLen > rRawHeader.size()) {
        return -1;
    }
    return headerLen;
};


/**
 * Active Object QT pattern - see tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SncJ3D-fO7g
 * See also: https://forum.qt.io/topic/140465/qt-6-x-qaudiosink-potential-bug
 */
class RtpWorker final : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //! mpThread cannot have parent, as we need to move this object
    //! Also, note most QT class members need 'this' as parent for
    //! thread affinity to work correctly.
    RtpWorker();

    //! these  deleted constructors and assignment operators are not
    //! strictly required as the QObject superclass prevents copy
    //! but left in for clarity
    RtpWorker(const RtpWorker&) = delete;
    RtpWorker(RtpWorker&&) noexcept = delete;
    RtpWorker& operator=(const RtpWorker&) = delete;
    RtpWorker& operator=(RtpWorker&&) noexcept = delete;

    //! virtual destructor overload
    ~RtpWorker() override {
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "cleanup");
        mpThread->wait();
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void stop();
    void start(const qint64, const QString&, const quint16,
        const qint64, const QByteArray&, const QByteArrayList&);
    void datagramsReady(const QByteArrayList&);
    void bytesWritten(qint64, bool);
    void watchdogStatusChanged(bool, const QString&);

    /**
     * Signal to asynchronously notify application thread .
     *
     * @param rStatusText [in] Status area notification text.
     * @param rStyleSheet [in] Text stylesheet.
     * @param timeout     [in] Timeout after which the text
     *                    disappears.
     */
    void workerStatusChange(const QString& rStatusText,
        const QString& rStyleSheet, int timeout = 0) const;

    /**
     * IPC Signal from worker thread used to safely update
     * mTXBufferList.
     *
     * @param aTSIncrement [in] Timestamp increment per datagram.
     * @param rAudioData   [in] raw multichannel audio.
     */
    void updateAudio(const qint64 aTSIncrement, const QByteArrayList& rAudioData);

    //! Add log entry
    void addLogEntry(const spdlog::level::level_enum, const QString&);

    // slots are all called while in the worker thread context
private Q_SLOTS:
    /**
     * Start signal handler.
     *
     * <p>This slot runs in the worker thread context.  Creates a
     * buffered list of transmit UDP datagrams.  Each datagram is prefixed
     * with an RTP header (including a sequence# & timestamp).
     *
     * <p>The first datagram will always have the marker bit set.
     *
     * @param aTSIncrement   [in] Timestamp increment per datagram.
     * @param rTargetIP      [in] Target IP address.
     * @param aTargetPort    [in] Target UDP port.
     * @param aDurationUsecs
     *                       [in] Duration (specified in microseconds) to
     *                       sleep between recurring timer callbacks.
     *                       This time represents the duration for all
     *                       <code>mTXBufferList</code> datagrams.
     * @param rHeader        [in] RTP header consisting of a QByteArray
     *                       containing an rtp_hdr_t with optional contributing
     *                       sources (up to 16) & rtp_hdr_ext_t fields & data if
     *                       the x bit of the rtp_hdr_t is set.
     * @param rAudioData     [in] raw multichannel audio.
     */
    void handleStart(
        const qint64 aTSIncrement,
        const QString& rTargetIP,
        const quint16 aTargetPort,
        const qint64 aDurationUsecs,
        const QByteArray& rHeader,
        const QByteArrayList& rAudioData);

    /**
     * Slot to handle captured audio data.
     *
     * <p>Saves the audio data to a QIODevice.
     *
     * @param rAudioBuffer [in] audio data with (containing valid
     *                     QAudioFormat).
     */
    void handleAudioCaptured(const QAudioBuffer& rAudioBuffer);

    /**
     * Audio updated slot handler.
     *
     * @param aTSIncrement [in] Timestamp increment per datagram.
     * @param rAudioData   [in] raw multichannel audio.
     */
    void handleAudioUpdated(
        const qint64 aTSIncrement,
        const QByteArrayList& rAudioData);

    /**
     * QUdpSocket slot readyRead handler.
     *
     * <p>Slot called when UDP data returned via echo to this
     * thread.  When called drain any pending datagrams and pet the
     * inactivity watchdog timer.
     */
    void readyRead();

    /**
     * Slot to handle bytes written.
     *
     * <p>Called when bytes successfully sent to target where we
     * emit the bytesWritten signal to update the stats area in the
     * GUI.
     *
     * @param aBytesWritten [in] number of bytes written to socket.
     */
    void handleBytesWritten(qint64 aBytesWritten) {
        // forward to GUI
        Q_EMIT bytesWritten(aBytesWritten, false);
    }

    /**
     * Stop slot handler.
     *
     * <p>This is called in the worker thread context.  Close open
     * timers, sockets, QAudioSources and QAudioSinks.
     */
    void handleStop();


    /**
     * Cleanup method - runs in worker thread context.
     */
    void cleanup();

    /**
     * Timer callback event handler.
     *
     * @param event [in] timer event.
     */
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent* event) override;
private:
    std::unique_ptr<QThread> mpThread;
    std::unique_ptr<QBasicTimer> mpTimer;
    std::unique_ptr<QTimer> mpWatchdog;
    std::unique_ptr<QUdpSocket> mpSocket;
    //! Audio Source (microphone).
    std::unique_ptr<QAudioSource> mpAudioSource;
    //! IODevice connected to mpAudioSource
    std::unique_ptr<IODeviceSource> mpIODeviceSource;
    //! Audio Sink (speaker).
    std::unique_ptr<QAudioSink> mpAudioSink;
    //! IODevice connected to mpAudioSink
    std::unique_ptr<IODeviceSink> mpIODeviceSink;

    QByteArrayList mTXBufferList;
    QHostAddress mTargetIP;
    quint16 mTargetPort;
    qint64 mTSIncrement;
    qint64 mTXCounter;
};
```